# Cast a String to Int to use it in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, function, edmx

Here is my Function under edmx:ConceptualModels:

```
<Function Name="IntConvert" ReturnType="Edm.Int32">
      <Parameter Name="stringvalue" Type="Edm.String" />
      <DefiningExpression>
        CAST(stringvalue AS Edm.Int32)
      </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

Here is the method to be translated:

```
public partial class SqlCustomFunctions
{
    [EdmFunction("MyModel", "IntConvert")]
    public static int IntConvert(string stringvalue)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This function can only be used in a LINQ to Entities query");            
    }
}
```

And here is the code to invoke the function:

```
filterResults = filterResults.OrderBy(x => SqlCustomFunctions.IntConvert(x.Badge)).Skip(start).Take(length);
```

The error message is as follows:

> base = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `'Int32
>   IntConvert(System.String)'` method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression."}

It looks like the edmx is not compiling the function or something like that.

What is causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: my opinion is you need to split it to 2 line. first, let convert it to int, after successful then go for LinQ

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
filterResults = filterResults
    .OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Badge))
    .Skip(start)
    .Take(length);
```

Tests is a table:

[image]

Comment: Very odd.  Works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, just realized this was using LINQ to SQL not LINQ over EF.

Comment: Is this going to mysql by chance?

Comment: Yes, I'm using in Linq. The database is SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with ..?

```
CAST(stringvalue AS int)
```

Comment: What's your EF version?

Comment: I'm not one hundred percent certain but I think that you need to update to newer version. Do you have any restriction?

Comment: I found this tag in the package.config file:
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: The other version i took from System.Data.Entity dll Reference

Comment: It looks so rare. It should work. Have you tried to remove all reference to EF , reference and package and reinstall EF 6 package?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if i'm able to do so! Have you had the same issue? Or needed to so something similar? I feel that something is missing, dunno what.

Comment: Open the package manager console and type `Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework`

Comment: It won't lose all projects references in Solution? I don't know if i will remember all of them to replace.